# Blur Mask Filters are not supported

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-rendering

I have one custom class which extends `View` class and in which i am just drawing some custom Bitmaps. Now problem is whenever i am using that class in xml, it creates rendering problem.

Here is my XML code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.custom.DrawingView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

There is nothing else i am using in xml but still error is there, i am also sharing screenshot for it, check below.

[image]

In my custom View class i have used BlurMaskFilter also

```
BlurMaskFilter blurMaskFilter = new BlurMaskFilter(5,
            BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
```

As you can see, i am not able to see preview of my layout and not even **Component Tree**.

Configuration :

```
Android studio : 2.1.3
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

Comment: @close voter : You can ask me what is unclear for you, as i have mentioned everything in question, still if anything i have missed please let me know instead of just giving close request.

Comment: It renders correctly if you set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` on your Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: It is already false in application tag itself, do i need to mention it again for activity also?

Comment: yes for particular `<activity>` tag.i think it is a bug

Comment: That also doesn't work.

Comment: what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: It's also 24 only

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` on your activity in`AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
 <activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
```

It works fine for me.